# Nginx reverse proxy multiple locations from a single domain

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, varnish

I'm trying to figure out how to set up Nginx as a reverse proxy from a single domain to multiple backend sites based on the location.

Nginx Config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    underscores_in_headers on;
    server_name test.example.com;

    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length  1100;
    gzip_buffers  4 32k;
    gzip_types    text/plain application/x-javascript text/xml text/css application/javascript;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;

location /page1/ {
    proxy_pass http://www.siteone.com/pageone;

    proxy_set_header Host www.siteone.com;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}

location /page2/ {
    proxy_pass http://www.sitetwo.com/pagetwo;

    proxy_set_header Host www.sitetwo.com;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

}
```

}

The problem is that static files (images, css, etc.) are all broken.  The initial request returns fine, but subsequent GET requests all go to the proxy subdomain (ex: test.example.com/css/style.css), and return 404 or 500 errors.

I tried to work around this with a static files location, or a catch all (e.g., "location /" or "location ~* ^(.*).(css|js|etc..)"), but I can't do that for both proxied sites.  As a workaround I also tried catching the referer URL and setting the catch-all's proxy_pass based on that, but it didn't work for everything and seemed kind of prone to failure.

I know this isn't a common setup, but unfortunately for our use case we can't use the more common method of a subdomain & server block for each proxied request.  Our requirement is for a single subdomain proxying to two or more backends based on the path (e.g., test.example.com/this-path -> backend.domain.com/can-be-anything).

We're using this proxy as a caching server, so I'd also be open to doing this with Varnish + Nginx for SSL termination if it better supports the use case.

Open to any suggestions from the community, and thanks!

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45934129/how-to-proxy-calls-to-specific-url-to-deluge-using-nginx

Comment: Your `proxy_pass` statements are wrong - if you have a trailing `/` on the `location`, you should have a trailing `/` on the `proxy_pass` URI - otherwise the aliasing will not work properly. See [this link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass).